# How to add a time selection on a page

Tags: android, ios, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I am creating an application in ionic 2. And I have not found this component down in the framework documentation.

I wonder if it exists or if there is a plugin that has the same behavior for ios. For android it need not be identical.

[image]

```
<engine name="android" spec="^6.2.3"/>
<engine name="ios" spec="^4.4.0"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.0.5"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.2"/>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.1"/>
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library:

https://github.com/byzg/ion2-datetime-picker

Installation

```
npm install ion2-datetime-picker --save
```

Comment: Ahmad, thank you, but after installation and build happened an error : Error: Cannot find module "moment"